# kubernetes ingress on GKE timeout and 502 during deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having a hard time figure out why ingress on GKE returns 502 errors and timeout during a deployment on a project.

To better understand the issue, I have setup a basic [hello application](https://github.com/ulule/helloapp) which takes the same workflow.

Here is the complete manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloapp
  labels:
    app: helloapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloapp
        image: gcr.io/${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}/helloapp:${HELLOAPP_VERSION}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http-server
          containerPort: 8080

        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /sys/health
            port: 8080

        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /sys/health
            port: 8080

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloapp
  labels:
    app: helloapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http-server
  selector:
    app: helloapp

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloapp-http
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: helloapp
    servicePort: 80
```

which contains an ingress, a service and customized probe for the pods.

The application is dead simple hello world application written in [Go](https://github.com/ulule/helloapp/blob/master/server.go#L16-L45).

During a deployment, if I siege the ingress healthcheck of my application and I notice:

```
HTTP/1.1 502     9.02 secs:     332 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 502     9.10 secs:     332 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     4.70 secs:     473 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     4.56 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.01 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.01 secs:     476 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.03 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.01 secs:     474 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     4.58 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     4.51 secs:     474 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.01 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.01 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     4.83 secs:     474 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 502     9.07 secs:     332 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
HTTP/1.1 200     0.02 secs:     475 bytes ==> GET  /sys/health
```

After a few minutes (generally 5-10), it stops and forwards the requests correctly.

Cluster information:

- Kubernetes version: 1.8.8
- Google cloud platform
- g1-small

Answer (score 0):

All is fine with your configs.  Looks like you have a problem during  your go-app starting: round-robing on your service is sending some requests to the non-started app in the pod, and that causes error with code 502.

How long does your app start  in the pod? You may add  `initialDelaySeconds`  to fix your error.

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloapp
        image: gcr.io/${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}/helloapp:${HELLOAPP_VERSION}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http-server
          containerPort: 8080

        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /sys/health
            port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60

        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /sys/health
            port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will try the `initialDelaySeconds`. The application is starting really fast (since it's just an hello world written in Go). One another thing I have noticed if I exposed directly the service as `LoadBalancer` I do not have the `502` errors during a deployment it seems really related to an issue in the ingress.

Comment: If you want to use Ingress try to use type `Cluster IP` for you service. When you use `NodePort`  some request cant be proceed because firewall issue.

Comment: still can't get this to work, even the service doesn't do its job with a `type: LoadBalancer`, I have updated the [manifest](https://github.com/ulule/helloapp/blob/master/scripts/kubernetes/manifests.yml) with a `rollingUpdate` strategy.

Comment: Could you check the firewall between nodes may one of your nodes can not response to request?

Comment: how do you check the firewall?